# getOutputMediaFile(int) is undefined for the type new Camera.PictureCallback(){} error confusing me

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I cannot figure out why this is occurring. It is probably a silly mistake that I cannot identify. Again the error is:

`getOutputMediaFile(int) is undefined for the type new Camera.PictureCallback(){}`

my code:

```
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: where you have created `getOutputMediaFile` method?

Comment: check the link agin http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media. i think you missed to copy the getOutputMediaFile method code :)

Comment: I also missed the `getOutputMediFile` method, the tutorial gives you the capture method before providing you with the `getOutputMediaFile` method, kind of backwards if you ask me.

Comment: Super Backwards. The guide wasn't written the clearest.

Answer (score 35):

If you arrived here because of the camera example scroll down further into the documentation the method is written at the last as it's common to both video and the image capture
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

Comment: lol I did not read your answer until I got sure there was something unusually wrong with that method name

Comment: LOL! I got stuck in the same dumb way!

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan so did a lot of us, happens to the best of us

Answer (score 2):

See Camera Android Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
Uri fileUri ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri=  getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });


}
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyCameraApp");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            tv.setText("Image saved to:\n"+data.getData());
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageURI(fileUri);
            //tv.setText(fileUri.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
              tv.setText("Cancelled");
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
             tv.setText("Can con be captured");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**

Try `importing android.provider.MediaStore.Files.FileColumns` and change `MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE to FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE`.

if you are calling Camera like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

// create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```